# With iOS 7's drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdate: method, what do I use as the view to call the method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

iOS 7 had the new method `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`, which is called on a view. Most examples seem to call it as `[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates]` but I'm wondering if the method documentation states it takes a screenshot of the full view hierarchy, what relevance does the first view have? Should I pass `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation means the complete view hierarchy *rooted at this view*. (As opposed to just the content of this view but none of its subviews.)

If you want to get a snapshot of the entire view hierarchy rooted in the key window, your code is correct.

Comment: The final bit of code is what you're referring to? If I use `self.view` it still works, though. Why is that?

Comment: Yes, I mean that using keyWindow is what you want if you want to capture the whole window. What do you mean by it "still works" if you use `self.view`. In most view controllers on iPhone, `self.view` is full-screen, so it would capture nearly everything you're seeing.

Comment: Do you know how I can get it to render everything under the view without including the view I am in?

Comment: @jowie You might want to start a separate question about that.

Comment: actually, I sorted it out... I hide the view I am in, do the image context, then unhide it again :)